# How to get file name auto when I browse a file to upload?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a upload form.
When I browse a file.Example. C:\mypicture\winter.jpg
I want to get file name and  fill in the text box 'winter.jpg' Automatically.

[image]
Thank .

Comment: I don't think you can do that unless your user allows your application to run into your system.

Comment: @mugur actually it is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/9RAmn/

Comment: @ Hello Peehaa,Your link is so useful,Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the demo in pure JS: http://jsfiddle.net/VaWDP/2/

```
<input type="file" id="file">
<input type="text" id="name">​

var input = document.getElementById('file');
var name = document.getElementById('name');

if (input.addEventListener) {
    input.addEventListener('change', add_filename);
} else if (input.attachEvent) {
    input.attachEvent('onchange', add_filename);
}

function add_filename()
{
    name.value = input.value.split(/\\|\//).pop();
}
```

​See the demo in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/SsW6t/

```
(function() {
    $('#file').change(function() {
        $('#name').val($(this).val().split(/\\|\//).pop());
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: Please Can you check your script? This script is not work for me.

Comment: Might either be me with a typo (did you get a JS error). I've fixed the type btw. I've tested it on IE9 and Chrome (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Websites should not be able to predetermine location of a data on your local disk.

If such thing would be possible some questions arise like:

- what if file does not exists
- what if file is security sensitive (e.g. encryption keys)

`@PeeHaa` commented that it is and therefore if such example exists it's clearly a security issue. This JSFiddle example does not work for me...

Comment: On what browser have you tested it. Because it works on Chrome and IE9. If the file is security sensitive why would you upload it to the website?

Comment: my appologee, I completely misunderstood what @WaiYan's question....
Your fiddle works as expected...

Comment: Hello Jperovic,It is not your mistake.Due to my english usage.I am beginner for english language.

Comment: @WaiYan I've seen (way) worse :-)